# for gods that are worshiped in both north and south india are their faces depicted similarly in the two areas?

Tags: culture, idols

do scriptures like agamas prescribe how different deities should look? to me except siva,durga/kali and ganesa all other gods look quite dissimilar in north and south india.

Comment: https://www.nativeplanet.com/travel-guide/krishna-temples-of-south-india/articlecontent-pf231-000101.html kerala vs https://www.google.com/search?q=krishna+temple+uttar+pradesh&client=firefox-b-1&biw=1280&bih=867&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=XqUOpu96H2uhEM%253A%252CspwaF8RtpQPI5M%252C_&usg=__ziBLQDTtf1TorvtNL7mBmzljbVc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw8pvin5LZAhWp64MKHYsHDVQQ9QEIbTAI#imgrc=YyvsWIGR5fvqGM:  uttar pradesh look totally different